# Angular and Handlebars together: template now translation

Tags: angularjs, cordova, templates, handlebars.js

I'm coding a Cordova app for mobile. I'm using Handlebars to compile the templates, and wanted to use Angular Translate to use translations in my app. Basically I'm compiling my template like this:

```
HomeView.prototype.template = Handlebars.compile($("#home-tpl").html());
```

In my #home-tpl template, I have a {[{ 'TITLE' | translate }]} tag, which should be used by Angular to translate, as I've changed the tags in Angular with

```
app.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
 $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{');
 $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}]}');
});
```

The problem is that Angular seems not to proceed the templates used by Handlebars. When I display my page, the tag is left as it {[{ 'TITLE' | translate }]}. Meaning that Handlebars does not process it (perfect), but neither is Angular (which is bad for me).

Does anyone know how to ensure that Angular will process the templates that I will feed to Handlebars?

Comment: Why do you even need handelbars? What does it do for you that angular templates don't do?

Comment: simply because I started the full devel with Handlebars. Now I'm thinking about using Angular translate, and I don't want to switch all the code to Angular templates...

Comment: Well now you have a full SPA framework installed over top of a jQuery driven page and expecting to cherry pick what the framework does. You will also need to use angular `$compile` which would normally be done in a directive

Comment: Could you be a bit more precise? Do you think it is possible?